# There is a way to send image to whatapp by link like text

Tags: javascript, whatsapp

I want to send an image to someone to WhatsApp by clicking on a link like we have for text

[Example](https://wa.me/15551234567?text=I'm%20interested%20in%20your%20car%20for%20sale) `https://wa.me/15551234567?text=I'm%20interested%20in%20your%20car%20for%20sale`

Comment: I am not aware of any other supported parameters besides `text`. Try putting the image URL as / into the text, and see what that gets you ...?

Comment: Formatting and tags.

Comment: it will send the url as text not image..